# Prove that $[\log(2x-3) / \log x] + [\log_x(x+6) / \log_{x+2} x] = 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

That question I got from my lecturer. However, I am not sure that the equality is true, since when I substitute x with any number, e.g. 10, it will not make an equality. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Substituting a particular value $x$ is a good way to show something is *not* an identity.  Perhaps $x=2$ is easier to use than $10$ here, in case there's uncertainty about the base of the first "log", since $\log 1 = 0$ regardless of the base.

Comment: It is not about substituting for x, it is about trying to find that value of x which when substituted for x would satisfy this inequality. Just about any value wouldn't satisfy this inequality

Comment: @Bhargav Firstly it is an equality and not an inequality. Secondly, in the question he clearly mention to prove it. So he just gave an example to disprove it thereby asking him to recheck his question.Cheers !

Answer (score 2):

$$\left.\frac{\log(2x-3)}{\log x}+\frac{\log_x(x+6)}{\log_{x+2}x}\right|_{x=2}=\frac{\log 1}{\log2}+\frac{\log_28}{\log_42}=0+\frac3{1/2}\neq 1$$

and thus the equality isn't such.

Perhaps you were asked *to solve the equation* ?

Comment: no, my lecturer asked me to prove it :(

Comment: Well, then (s)he either made a mistake, or else wanted you to discover it, or you miscopied the exercise from the blackboard...or something. The equality isn't true.